# How to use NodeReal's Meganode service in BSC Testnet?

Tags: testnets, nodes, bsc, web3-providers

This question seems even a bit stupid to me, but I read in [Binance documentation](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html#3rd-party-provider) about [Nodereal](https://nodereal.io/), and they state in their [documentation about Meganode service](https://nodereal.gitbook.io/nodereal/intro/core-products/meganode), the following:

> Supports mainnet and **testnets** via client-compatible JSON-RPC, over
> HTTPS and WSS.

That looks great, but when I enter to the console of Meganode, I only see the Mainnet endpoint for HTTPS and Websocket in the BSC.

My question is: Where is, and how to use, the **testnet endpoint from Meganode's** service?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a bsc testnet node all around. Finally I found it on NodeReal, you can choose BSC mainnet/testnet or ETH mainnet on the app's settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).